# Getting started with a project using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, payment-gateway

Ok, I've got Zend all set up and my hello world pages working.

**Personally, I'd rather code this from scratch, but I'm trying to find out how to use Zend to save time when making similar projects over and over again.**

I want to:

Admin:

1. Create multiple admin accounts
2. Have database-stored admin options that will be available on all php pages for both admin and public pages (like global on/off switch for the entire public site, homepage title, guest permissions, etc)

Public:

1. Have the user be able to create and sign in
2. User can fill out personal information
3. Recurring payment processing

My quesiton is, what Zend modules do I want to use? I want to use the zend framework to the best it can and not write any code that I don't have to.

Comment: It sounds like you maybe need to consider using Magento which is built on Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of the payment processing your app is doing CRUD, so you will likely use the MVC and Db classes of ZF then. For authentication you'd use a `Zend_Auth` adapter. And thats it already. Of course ZF provides much more classes than that, but given from your description YAGNI.

Also, keep in mind, that ZF promotes a use-at-will architecture. You can take whatever you like from it. It is not a full stack framework though and there is very little automagic in it. ZF can do a lot with some additional work, but if you are looking for [something like this](http://www.symfony-project.org/screencast/admin-generator) out of the box, you are probably better off with Symfony or another full stack framework.

Well, as for the other ZF classes, why not RT*M ;)

Answer (score 1):

basically, you will need the MVC implementation so read about
Zend_Controller , Zend_View and Zend_Application too.

for DB interaction, there is Zend_Db but I don't prefer using it, it will be better to go with a good O/R mapper like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) . there is planes for integrating ZF with Doctrine in the future so using it now, is a good idea.

for Authentication use Zend_Auth and for Authorization use Zend_ACL.

Zend_Form will make creating and validating your forms easier with its integration with Zend_Validate